# Django ORM: Get the last item from an update set based on filters and ordered

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I have a table:

```
`UPDATES` TABLE
product_id  |  sales_rank  |  updated_on
____________________________________________
1            500            2015-12-17 15:19
2            600            2015-12-17 15:20
3            700            2015-12-17 15:21
1            550            2015-12-18 15:19
2            550            2015-12-18 15:20
3            1000           2015-12-18 15:21
```

I have another relating table:

```
`PRODUCTS` TABLE
product_id  |  title  |  brand  |  picture
__________________________________________
1            iPod      Apple     http://cdn...
2            iPad      Apple     http://cdn...
3            iPhone    Apple     http://cdn...
```

A user should be able to search specific product traits and also retrieve the latest update.  For example, if I search for title 'iPhone', I should receive row 6 from the `UPDATES` table.  If I search for brand 'Apple', I should receive rows 4,5,and 6 from the `UPDATES` table.

What I've been doing is simply doing a group by on product_id and selecting 'max(updated_on)' to get the list of products.  However, there is a problem here, because I want to also order by the sales rank...

The database I'm working with has 200,000 products and over 3 million update rows at the moment.  I need to return the latest 500 update rows (remember, ordered by sales rank, too) that can satisfy certain traits.

I'm pretty lost and may be over thinking it but would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: What's difficult about order by sales_rank? Why can't you do `order_by('sales_rank')`?

Comment: When I add this, it adds 'sales_rank' to the group by clause, so if the sales rank differs across updates, they will not be grouped upon only product_id.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you do `Updates.objects.values('product_id').annotate(latest=Max('updated_on')).order_by('-sales_rank')[:500]`, what's going to happen?

Comment: This results in: `GROUP BY "products_updates"."product_id", "products_updates"."sales_rank" ORDER BY "products_updates"."sales_rank" DESC LIMIT 500`, which will result in the same product being returned multiple times when a sales rank change occurs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, but I have similar stuff and I tried it out, it doesn't group by both things. Are you sure you only put `product_id` in `values` statement? What if you just execute the raw query in your database shell without grouping by `sales_rank`?

Comment: `[42803] ERROR: column "products_updates.sales_rank" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 795`